# How to resolve java.net.MalformedURLException?

Tags: android, malformedurlexception

I am getting this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found[java.lang.StringBuilder]
```

When the following line is getting executed:

```
url = new URL(urlString.toString());
```

urlString stores the following value:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=25.04202,121.534761&daddr=25.05202,121.554761&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml
```

What causes this Exception?

Comment: Try logging the urlString.toString() value as the parser complains that it starts with the value "java.lang.StringBuilder"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are that you didn't clean after changing from

```
url = new URL( urlString );
```

to

```
url = new URL(urlString.toString());
```

You should log the value of the parameter passed to the constructor of URL. 
It's not what you think it should be.

urlString would print a value in the form of java.lang.StringBuilder@
thus throwing the exception if you try to build a url out of that.

But using to String will print the value of the content string built by the stringbuilder.

Comment: yes when I print it shows url=[Ljava.lang.StringBuilder;@412b0fb0, but when I check its value while debugging it shows the proper URL. What do u mean by logging the value of the param to the constructor of URL? What else should I do?

Comment: I meant log the value of the parameter *passed* to the constructor of URL. Did you clean the project. For sure, the problems comes from here.

Comment: Thank you so much Snicolas.. I figured out the problem. I was using AsyncTask and was not passing params correctly. Its now resolved :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with exception handling ...

```
String urlString = "https://www.example.com/";
URL url = null;

// handle Exception
try {
    url = new URL(urlString);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("The URL is not valid.");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

// print
if (url != null) {
    System.out.println(url.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this exception if your network firewall blocking that URL.

Answer (score 0):

replace url with php file address placed over server instedof html